# How to change value in config file doesnt provide the value

Tags: go

I want to do some watch when env variable/ config property value is changed
I’ve found viper which should support this scenario but didn't able 
to make it work. 
I see that the `OnConfigChange` is called but the value from config
is not taken from the config when it change. The config is loaded successfully

I’ve created a sample to demonstrate the issue.

File `cfg.go`

`go/src/myproj/configuration/cfg.go`

```
package configuration

import (
   "fmt"
   "os"
   "strings"

   "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
   "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
   "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

const (
   varLogLevel     = "log"
   varPathToConfig = "config.file"
)

type Configuration struct {
   v *viper.Viper
}

func New() *Configuration {
   c := Configuration{
      v: viper.New(),
   }

   c.v.SetDefault(varPathToConfig, "./config.yaml")
   c.v.SetDefault(varLogLevel, "info")
   c.v.AutomaticEnv()
   c.v.SetConfigFile(c.GetPathToConfig())
   err := c.v.ReadInConfig() // Find and read the config file
   logrus.WithField("path", c.GetPathToConfig()).Warn("loading config")
   // just use the default value(s) if the config file was not found
   if _, ok := err.(*os.PathError); ok {
      logrus.Warnf("no config file '%s' not found. Using default values", c.GetPathToConfig())
   } else if err != nil { // Handle other errors that occurred while reading the config file
      panic(fmt.Errorf("fatal error while reading the config file: %s", err))
   }
   setLogLevel(c.GetLogLevel())
   // monitor the changes in the config file
   c.v.WatchConfig()
   c.v.OnConfigChange(func(e fsnotify.Event) {
      logrus.WithField("file", e.Name).Warn("Config file changed")
      setLogLevel(c.GetLogLevel())
   })
   return &c
}

// GetLogLevel returns the log level
func (c *Configuration) GetLogLevel() string {
   s := c.v.GetString(varLogLevel)
   return s
}

// GetPathToConfig returns the path to the config file
func (c *Configuration) GetPathToConfig() string {
   return c.v.GetString(varPathToConfig)
}

func setLogLevel(logLevel string) {
   logrus.WithField("level", logLevel).Warn("setting log level")
   level, err := logrus.ParseLevel(logLevel)
   if err != nil {
      logrus.WithField("level", logLevel).Fatalf("failed to start: %s", err.Error())
   }
   logrus.SetLevel(level)
}
```

And I create some sample web-application server to make the program running in background
(to be able to change the config and see wheatear something is changed )

`go/src/myproj`

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "net/http"
   "myproj/configuration"
)

func main() {

   cfg := configuration.New()
   fmt.Println(cfg)

   http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
   http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

The problem is that the function `GetLogLevel()` bring the old value and not read the value from config ?

This is the sample of config-file (I've put it sibling to the `main.go` file under the root project folder

**This is the project structure**

```
go/src/myproj
  - main.go
  - configuration #folder
  -- cfg.go
  - config.yaml
```

```
data:
  config.yaml: 'log: debug'
```

when I change it from `info` to `debug` (or other option) I see that the event `watch` was raised but
it not fetch the new value (like debug). Any idea?

**update**
when I change the configfile like @Tom suggested I was able to see that the log was change but not the level, it stay on `warn`

This is the logs , I still see the warn

```
WARN[0000] loading config                                path=./config.yaml
WARN[0000] setting log level                             fields.level=info
&{0xc00012e300}
WARN[0008] Config file changed                           file=config.yaml
WARN[0008] setting log level                             fields.level=error
WARN[0020] Config file changed                           file=config.yaml
WARN[0020] setting log level                             fields.level=debug
WARN[0060] Config file changed                           file=config.yaml
WARN[0060] setting log level                             fields.level=warn
```

Comment: "I want to do some watch when env variable value is changed" -- This won't ever happen while the program is running, unless your program itself changes it.

Comment: @Flimzy - currently I want to check if config is changed ( this is working  the event was raised) but the`new` value (which was changed in the conifgfile ) is not reflected, any idea ?

Comment: @JennyM where is `viper_env/configuration` coming from?

Comment: @TomTrebicky - it should be `myproj` ,I've updated the post , thanks. it reference to the first file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code as far as I can see since `fsnotify` truly does trigger. So the culprit has to be in parsing. The first call to `setLogLevel(c.GetLogLevel())` outside your `onConfigChange` callback returns an incorrect value. Change the contents of your yaml file to just

```
log: 'level'
```

and all should be working as desired.

The logrus package supports the following levels (as of the time of writing) in order: `Panic`, `Fatal`, `Error`, `Warn`, `Info`, `Debug`, and `Trace`. The corresponding methods are: `logrus.Panic()`, `logrus.Fatal()`, `logrus.Warn()`, `logrus.Info()`, `logrus.Debug()`, and `logrus.Trace()`.

For example, if the current level is set to `Warn`, the call `logrus.Warn("boo!")` shall output `boo!`. However, calling `logrus.Info("boo!")` will show nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I miss your point :) , how does the log level will be changed? I want that when I change the value from `config.yaml: 'log: debug'` to `config.yaml: 'log: error' `, it will change the log output from `debug ` to `error`  , how can I achive that with your proposal ?

Comment: I am talking about the **config.yaml** file itself and its contents. Instead of the whole two lines of `data:\nconfig.yaml: 'log: debug'` make it only what I posted `log: 'level'` where level is w/e you want: `info`, `debug`, `warn`, etc.

Comment: thanks! Tom 1+ , please see my update still I see everthing with `warn` and not changed according to the log level, any idea as inside the watch I update the log level

Comment: That's because of this line in your `setLogLevel` function: `logrus.WithField("level", logLevel).Warn("setting log level")`. You print the line at the `warn` level. Change your config option to level `error` and all these messages disappear. Internally, logrus' print tests whether the requested log level `logrus.WithField().Warn()` is less or equal than the level set by `logrus.SetLevel()` and if it is it prints it.

Comment: HI, please see if you can assist also here, it's similar question but now on K8S :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57936885/k8s-change-config-map-and-update-app-log-level   , thanks!